# Notification Icon in status bar is not changing in few android devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin, icons, android-notifications

How do I can change the color of notification icon in status bar against the other application themes?

[image]

From the above image the last icon belongs to my application. But I can see the other applications **notification icon color** is changing **against theme**(Compare two images).

This is working fine in few devices. But this is not working in some other devices. For example the above picture I took from Huawei, but the other application icon color changed.

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: What file type is the icon you are using? Png or svg?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a compatibility issue based on different mobile provider. Can you please tell what base theme are you using for your application? You can find that information at your app(in the android view for android studio)->java->res->values->styles.xml .

EDIT

Remove DarkActonBar and try to only use DayNight. Then enforce dark action bar by checking the mode in the launcher activity’s onCreate.

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar